# How do I download a PDF from an HTML webpage-submitted POST form using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, html, post

I'm trying to programmatically download some PDF document with a C# windows form application. Right now, I've got far enough to get a unique URL for each page that goes to download the PDF.

Each link is a webpage that submits a form via POST as soon as the page is loaded

```
function window_onload() {
                Form1.submit();
            }
```

Then the PDF starts downloading. I would like to stop the PDF from downloading and save it automatically to my local machine. The reason I want to do this is because there are around 15-20 PDFs that I need to download every week.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [httpwebrequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) object.

depending on the size pdfs, and response time of servers you could do this asynchronously or synchronously.  This is the synchronous flavor using the `GetResponse()` method.

```
void DoPDFDownload(string strMyUrl, string strPostData, string saveLocation)
{
    //create the request
    var wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myURL);
    wr.Method = "POST";
    wr.ContentLength = strPostData.Length;
    //Identify content type... strPostData should be url encoded per this next    
    //declaration
    wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    //just for good measure, set cookies if necessary for session management, etc.
    wr.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(wr.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        sw.Write(strPostData);
    }

    var resp = wr.GetResponse();

    //feeling rather lazy at this point, but if you need further code for writing
    //response stream to a file stream, I can provide.
    //...

}
```

The following is a little method you could copy/paste into LINQPad to get an idea of how these classes work.

```
void DoSpeedTestDownloadFromFCC()
{

string strMyUrl = "http://data.fcc.gov/api/speedtest/find?latitude=38.0&longitude=-77.5&format=json";
    //create the request
    var wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strMyUrl);
    wr.ContentLength = strPostData.Length;
            //Note that I changed the method for the webservice's standard.
            //No Content type on GET requests.
    wr.Method = "GET";
    //just for good measure, set cookies if necessary for session management, etc.
    wr.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();


    var resp = wr.GetResponse();

    //...
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
                    //here you would write the file to disk using your preferred method
                    //in linq pad, this just outputs the text to the console.
        sr.ReadToEnd().Dump();
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the strPostData? Also, could you help with the response stream to file stream?

Comment: strPostData is the data to be sent to the server in the form of a string.  Something like "filename=my%20pdf%20file.pdf".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding I'll have an edit momentarily with more information on saving the file to disk.

Comment: Also note, this doesn't interrupt any browser function, but the web request 'acts' as a web browser.  This class is very powerful, and can incorporate proxies.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class DownloadLibrary
 {
 public static string getContentType(string Fileext)
 {
string contenttype = "";
switch (Fileext)
{
case ".xls":
contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
break;
case ".doc":
contenttype = "application/msword";
break;
case ".ppt":
contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
break;
case ".pdf":
contenttype = "application/pdf";
break;
case ".jpg":
case ".jpeg":
contenttype = "image/jpeg";
break;
case ".gif":
contenttype = "image/gif";
break;
case ".ico":
contenttype = "image/vnd.microsoft.icon";
break;
case ".zip":
contenttype = "application/zip";
break;
default: contenttype = "";
break;
}
return contenttype;
}

public static void downloadFile(System.Web.UI.Page pg, string filepath)
{
pg.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + new FileInfo(filepath).Name);
pg.Response.ContentType = clsGeneral.getContentType(new FileInfo(filepath).Extension);
pg.Response.WriteFile(filepath);
pg.Response.End();
}
}
```

References: http://dotnetacademy.blogspot.com/2010/07/code-to-download-file-on-buttton-click.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.ClearContent();    
Response.ClearHeaders();    
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";                            
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\";");    
Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);    
Response.End();
```

It will download file with the given `filename` to your local disk.